# OS Freezes but Mouse Continues to Move

Tags: mouse

The whole OS freezes, no functionality whatsoever, not system, not apps, not media, not nothing. But the mouse cursor is still responsive, movement-wise, but no clicks. There are a lot of **similar** posts here, but nothing quite like mine. Also I've noticed the answers to be less than impressively helpful.

This happens every time after a reboot after about five to ten minutes, anywhere in between, during normal functionality of the system, me doing normal things.

Ubuntu 20.04.

Mike

Comment: Tell us your configuration... what CPU, what video card, etc. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`.

Answer (score 0):

The situation in which everything freezes except for the mouse cursor can be caused by using old proprietary graphics drivers. If this is the case in your system, it would be solvable by replacing Ubuntu 20.04 by a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04. I do not recommend upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04, because upgrading from one LTS version of Ubuntu to the next is not recommended until the first point release of the new LTS version is launched which usually happens in late August four months after its initial release date.